# many to many polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure how to create this, I'd like to create a many-to-many polymorphic association.

I have a `question` model, which belongs to a `company`.

Now the question can `has_many users`, `groups`, or `company`. Depending on how you assign it.

I'd like to be able to assign the question to one / several users, or one / several groups, or the company it belongs to.

How do I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I would add a Assignment model which acts as an intersection between questions and the entities which are assigned to it.

#### Create the table

Lets run a generator to create the needed files:

`rails g model assignment question:belongs_to assignee_id:integer assignee_type:string`

Then let's open up the created migration file `(db/migrations/...__create_assignments.rb)`:

```
class CreateAssignments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :assignments do |t|
      t.integer :assignee_id
      t.string :assignee_type
      t.belongs_to :question, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.index [:assignee_id, :assignee_type]
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

If you're paying attention here you can see that we add a foreign key for `question_id` but not `assignee_id`. That's because the database does not know which table `assignee_id` points to and cannot enforce referential integrity*. We also add a compound index for `[:assignee_id, :assignee_type]` as they always will be queried together.

#### Setting up the relationship

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :assignee, polymorphic: true
end
```

The `polymorpic: true` option tells ActiveRecord to look at the `assignee_type` column to decide which table to load `assignee` from.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, as: :assignee
  has_many :questions, through: :assignments
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, as: :assignee
  has_many :questions, through: :assignments
end    

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, as: :assignee
  has_many :questions, through: :assignments
end
```

Unfortunately one of the caveats of polymorphic relationships is that you cannot eager load the polymorphic assignee relationship. Or declare a `has_many :assignees, though: :assignments`.

One workaround is:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, as: :assignee
  has_many :questions, through: :assignments

  def assignees
    assignments.map(&:assignee)
  end
end
```

But this can result in very inefficient SQL queries since each assignee will be loaded in a query!

Instead you can do something like this:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments

  # creates a relationship for each assignee type
  ['Company', 'Group', 'User'].each do |type|
    has_many "#{type.downcase}_assignees".to_sym,
        through: :assignments,
        source: :assignee,
        source_type: type
  end

  def assignees
    (company_assignees + group_assignees + user_assignees)
  end
end
```

Which will only cause one query per assignee type which is a big improvement.